# How can I create a local function in my bashrc?

Tags: bash, bashrc

My .bashrc had some code that was repetitive so I used a function to simplify it

```
do_stuff() {
  local version=$1
  export FOO_${version}_X="17"
  export FOO_${version}_Y="42"
}

do_stuff '5.1'
do_stuff '5.2'
```

However, now when I use my shell the "do_stuff" name is in scope so I can tab-complete and run that function (potentially messing up my environment variables). Is there a way to make "do_stuff" visible only inside the .bashrc?

Comment: If you diddn't nee the export, you could also use `()` to make a subshell. Another possibility for simple cases is using a `for version in 5.1 5.2` loop, although this lets `version` escape.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `unset` as last line in your `.bashrc`:

```
unset -f do_stuff
```

will delete/unset the function `do_stuff`.

To delete/unset the variables invoke it as follows:

```
unset variablename
```

Comment: Is unset really the only way here? Well, I guess if I use a really long and ugly name for my function the chance of it clashing with something else won't be that big...

Comment: If that's the problem check frist if the function exists: `if type do_stuff >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo "exists"; else echo "dont"; fi`.

Comment: This won't work if `do_stuff` is used inside another function. When you call that function, you will get `bash: do_stuff: command not found`. I know this isn't the exact case the op was talking about but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: Nice and [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_29).

Answer (score 16):

The other option is to use underscores like in other scripted languages to indicate you do not intend for this function to be public. The likelihood of you typing _do_foo is pretty small and also unlikely to conflict with anyone else.

Comment: Yes, do use "_" to indicate intent to have a private function, but this has nothing to do with conflicts.  Anyone can need "_debug()" or "_safe_copy()".  If there is something that helps avoid conflicts, it has *nothing to do* with underscores.

Answer (score 5):

Only solution I can think of is underscore it and give it a pretty unique name, maybe even namespacing it with dots like a fancypants language ([but this will not work in ye olde `sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771743/function-name-valid-in-bash-but-not-in-sh)).

Heck, this won't have any conflicts:

```
_my_foobar_method_91a3b52d990f4a9f9d5d9423ec37b64c () {
    # Custom proprietary logic protected ID 10 T intellectual property copyright clauses.
    cat <<< `echo $(xargs printf <<< "$1")`; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in a comment, you may use a subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash

. <(
  do_stuff() {
    local version="$1" valid='^\w+$'

    [[ "$version" =~ $valid ]] &&
      cat <<SIDE               || echo "$FUNCNAME: invalid '$version'" >&2
export FOO_${version}_X=17
export FOO_${version}_Y=42
SIDE
  }

  do_stuff 5.0 # FOO_5.0_X is "not a valid identifier"
  do_stuff 5_1
  do_stuff 5_2
)

do_keep() { :; } # just get sure the report below actually works

set | egrep '(do_|FOO_)' |  sed -e 's,^,set:\x09,'
```

We build another script on subshell standard output for the only side effect we desire (using `here` document `<<SIDE`). Then we source with `.`.

The power of 'mise en abime' in `sh` is a frightening source of wonder.

Comment: For those wondering what _mise en abime_ meant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_en_abyme